# Is it possible to capture ieee802.11 management and control frames from the same phone using android APP or tcpdump on root device?

Tags: ieee-802.11, wireshark, tcpdump

I am trying to study the traffic between the mobile and access points. So I have phone Galaxy Nexus which does not support monitoring mode but still support promiscuous mode. Unfortunately, I try many android apps Shark for root , native shark, tpacket and Tcpdump. all of them cannot capture any ieee802.11 frames(control, management and beacon frames).

Comment: You are probably better off asking this on [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/). We can't tell you the capability of the hardware in your end-device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without monitor mode, there will be no access to non-traffic frames. Use a 3rd device (PC) that *does* support monitor mode to record radio traffic.